# Are FULL documents required for discovery or will portions suffice?

Tags: litigation, discovery

Simple question. When supplying documents for discovery must one supply the whole document or just pertinent portions?

Example - In dispute is a % or a closing date. The key info is available in a 10-page contract, on page 2. MUST one include the whole 10 pages or just the pages with the requested info?